# 1:1 aspect column, other shrink/grows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a layout, as follows:

[image]

The image is square, and should always be full height of container (and width). Content is variable height, and should be vertically centered.

So far, I've tried using flexbox however while I can get the image to be full height, I can't get it to fit the width. It ends up looking like this:

[image]

Perhaps using `display: table` might be better, however I haven't been able to find any good documentation. Any suggestions?

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container > * {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.container .avatar img {
  height: 100%;
}

.container .avatar {
  
}

.container .content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .content p {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">    
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Some text balh blah
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/cakexcrx/ OR this https://jsfiddle.net/cakexcrx/1/?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself, using a trick found on a codepen (unfortunately I don't have the source link still or I'd link for further info). Can be fixed using `:after` on the column you want to keep 1:1:

```
.container .avatar:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```